# Count unique values of column and store in a new column

Tags: python, pandas

```
# Dummy df.
data = [
  [11, 'a'],
  [11, 'b'],
  [10, 'c'],
  [9, 'd'],
  [1, 'e'],
  [1, 'f']
]
column_name = ['freq', 'recordings']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=column_name)
```

Print `df`:

```
freq     id
  11      a
  11      b
  10      c
  9       d
  1       e
  1       f
```

I want to see how many times every value of `freq` is stored. Desired output:

```
 df = 

freq     recordings
  11      2
  10      1
   9      1
   1      2
```

Comment: `df.groupby('freq',as_index=False,sort=False).count()` ?

Comment: A General rule of SC is to at least provide an attempt to how you tried to solve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = [
    [11, 'a'],
    [11, 'b'],
    [10, 'c'],
    [9, 'd'],
    [1, 'e'],
    [1, 'f']
]
column_name = ['freq', 'recordings']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=column_name)
```

Solution:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(df.freq)
```

Output:

```
Counter({11: 2, 10: 1, 9: 1, 1: 2})
```